# Angular js plugin not showing up in eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, plugins

I have installed Angularjs plugin in Eclipse, but it is not showing up in configure section

[image]

Comment: You mean that you hav enot "Convert To Angular project...."? If it that have an existing .tern-project in your project? If yes, have angular declared in the plugins section. Otherwise have you some errors in the error log view?

Comment: i got it resolved by installing it in Kepler version of eclipse,.. might be its version problem,..

Answer (score 0):

Configure -> convert to AngularJS Project...
Then you can see the suggestions.